# Component var is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a var `User` that's undefined after I call my service. Here is the code :

```
import { User } from './user/user';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  { 

  user: User;

  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
  ){}

  getUser(): User{
      this.appService.getUser().then(user => { this.user = user; this.setUserRoles();})
      console.log(this.user)
      return this.user
  }
```

This is my AppService :

```
import { User } from './user/user';
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class AppService{

    private Url = 'https://cara4-c.na.premiertech.com:451/api/data/';  // URL to web api
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getUser(): Promise<User> {
        return this.http.get(this.Url + 'adfsIdentity')
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as User)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

The console.log() show me undefined.

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think it should work?

Comment: Hi Alex, could you post you AppService?

Comment: @EmileCantero Updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place console.log inside the subscribe,

```
  this.appService.getUser().then(user => { this.user = user; 
      this.setUserRoles();}
      console.log(this.user)      
  )
  getUser(): User{
     if(this.user){
      return this.user
      };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

getUser() is as async call so it will take some time update the user value but console statement and will return statement will execute immediately  after invoke getUser() call. so return user will return null value

you should your console statement inside then statement.

```
getUser(): User{
      this.appService.getUser().then(user => { this.user = user; this.setUserRoles();
console.log(this.user);
})
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but how does I use this.user in another function ?

Comment: if you want use in another function than you should call that function inside Then. otherwise create User Object while starting App and pass User Object as input to that component.

Comment: @AlexCaron for exemple you could do that using ngFor but you can do multiple things: <div *ngFor="let user of appService.users">{{user.data.hosts}}</div>

Comment: @AlexCaron look that video, for me it help a lot to understand the benefits of using observalbles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLGCCpOWFFw&t=1676s

Comment: as per my knowledge its bad design to create observalbles to manage function call hierarchy inside single component. My suggestion will be create child component and pass as input.

Comment: @EmileCantero Thank you! I'm using appComponent.users in my *ngIf and now it's working! :)

Comment: @AlexCaron you welcome please vote and flag my answear if it was helpful